# How do I reduce space before and after HRule?

Tags: spacing, rules

I have a command:

```
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}}
```

and it produces a thickness I am happy with but the space before and after the line is far too large and taking up much of my document. How can I change this?

Comment: It mostly depends on how and where you want to use it.

Comment: It is dividing sections on my Resume - but with too much vertical spacing above and below

Comment: I think a MWE which includes a preamble and creates the same problem would be useful here.

Comment: `\par\nopagebreak\medskip\hrule\medskip` could be better, but it depends on many factors. Please, try and present a minimal example.

Comment: Have you given `\hrule` (default thickness: 0.4pt) a try?

Comment: hrule is a much nicer vertical spacing but it goes all the way to the far right of the page, and everything else is restricted by a margin somehow.. I'm sorry I'm using my brother's template and am not aware really of how it's working

Comment: It's essential that you provide an MWE that includes all relevant considerations, such as the fact that you appear to be working with narrow columns.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version of `\HRule` that allows you to adjust the gap above/below with an optional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\HRule}[1][\medskipamount]{\par
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+#1}
  \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}\par
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\parskip-.5\baselineskip+#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
Here is some regular text.

\HRule

Here is some regular text.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
Here is some regular text.

\HRule[0pt]

Here is some regular text.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The default gap (shown on the left) is `\medskipamount` (`6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`), but you can adjust that. For example, on the right a gap of `0pt` is set.

Answer (score -1):

Is the following command working for you? :

```
\newcommand{\HRule}{\hrule\vspace{0.2mm}}
```

Comment: This looks like an answer, but it does not address the issue raised by the OP.