# Inserting a colored box to page background leaves gap

Tags: margins, rules, eso-pic

I'd like to have a colored box in the upper part of every page. Even though it's a simple task, I cannot make it work. Having looked for answers here and in the eso-pic package discription does not bring me any further.

Neither playing around with minipages as suggested here
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tips_and_Tricks#Sidebar_with_information
has solved it.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
    \AtPageUpperLeft{
        {\color{red}%
            \rule[-1cm]%offset PageBorder
                {\paperwidth}%{14.8cm}
                {1cm}%height
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

When I run pdfLaTeX, I always have a small gap, say .1mm on the left border. Did not dare to try that [How to I reduce space before and after HRule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135617/how-to-i-reduce-space-before-and-after-hrule) , though.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is excellent, thank you for providing a complete MWE, it really helps :) Nice indentation, too :) Welcome!

Comment: Thank you @cmhuges. I've already asked a question about a year ago, cannot recall the login, though. Nevertheless, I have an account on ask.libreoffice on the same nickname.

Comment: you're missing a `%` symbol: `\AtPageUpperLeft{%`

Comment: Wow, that was quick, thank you! How come % actually has a function? I've thought it is used for marking comments, only.

Anyhow, there are still two questions;
(1) Would you solve the issue in a more elegant way and 
(2) can you mark this as an answer for me to give you points?

Comment: have a look at [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453) :) Thanks for the offer of rep points, but Herbert has already provided an answer which covers it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{%
        {\color{red}%
            \rule[-1cm]%offset PageBorder
                {\paperwidth}%{14.8cm}
                {1cm}%height
        }%
    }%
}
```

If you are not sure then put at every line end  the comment character `%` to avoid trailing spaces. A linebreak is internally replaced by a space. However, in your example the one at `\AtPageUpperLeft{%` is only important.

Comment: Thank you too @Herbert for solving this! I did not know about trailing spaces. Great you have pointed that out!