# Why should I escape my line endings?

Tags: comments

I've seen many LaTeX Code Snippets like this one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184427/76157)

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{%
        {\color{red}%
            \rule[-1cm]%offset PageBorder
                {\paperwidth}%{14.8cm}
                {1cm}%height
        }%
    }%
}
```

where  most line endings - if not all - are escaped with `%`. I don't understand the reason, as `%` marks (per definition) text, which will not interpreted by the compiler. So What is the reason, people escape their line endings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after starting my question, I've found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/76157), which answers my question. Sorry.